# How to set DatePicker value equal yesterday in xaml in xamarin.form?

Tags: xamarin, datepicker

To set the `Date` attribute in xaml equal today we can use `Today` attribute as following:

`xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

`<DatePicker Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}"/>`

I've tried to set it by using `AddDays` method but it couldn't help.

`<DatePicker Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)}"/>` Does not work.

So is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussions the best answer I have found is using a helper like following:

In xaml:

`xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Helpers"`

`<DatePicker Date="{x:Static helpers:DateTimeHelper.Yesterday}"/>`

While helper is:

```
namespace Helpers
{
    public class DateTimeHelper {
        public static System.DateTime Yesterday
        {
            get { return System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date from the controller.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PostingDatePicker" />

PostingDatePicker.Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

Another way is that you bind the date from your ViewModel,

Xaml

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PostingDatePicker" Date="{Binding PostingDate}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public DateTime PostingDate {get; set;}

PostingDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

**Updated Answer:**

If you want to update the date only through XAML, you can use converters,

```
 <DatePicker x:Name="PostingDatePicker" Date="{Binding PostingDate, Converter={local:DateConverter}}"/>
```

create a class which inherits IValueConverter,

```
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

At runtime, your datepicker date will be updated with yesterday's date.

Comment: Thanks but I'm asking about if there a way for setting it from xaml code without binding and of course without using `datePicker.Date =` in cs.